# uninstall GRUB for use windows boot system

Tags: grub2

I have a problem with boot system with 3 OS(Windows 10, Windows 7, Linux).

Before, when booting the system (dsa disk), the windows 10 boot system could select between that 3 OS without any problem.

But, one day, when selecting the Linux OS in the windows boot system (where GRUB had installed) the GRUB failed and to fix it I have done:

```
sudo mount / dev / sda3 / mnt (sda3 is my linux partition)
sudo grub-install --root-directory = / mnt / dev / sda
```

Now, when I turn on the PC, GRUB load first (with errors), instead of the windows boot system, but I do not want this.

How can I undo my last change (grub-install) so rescue previous boot system (from windows 10)?

Comment: Tell us what you have done. Trying to use a Linux live system is a question of common sense. I suspect it is easier to erase grub from the Windows side, but I would have to Google for it, you can do it too, and it is out of topic here.

Comment: thank you, i made it from the Windows side and now i can select my 3 OS, but if i select Linux OS then the GRUB ternimal is opened with: `GNE GRUB version 2.02beta2-9ubuntu1 (minimal BASH-like line edtiting is supported...)
grub >`  .   so, I would like to remove the GRUB because I use the windows boot system